# The problem between over-sampled, down-sampled data and original data using SVM with unbalanced data

Tags: classification, svm, binary-data, unbalanced-classes, oversampling

I am working on a classifier that is supposed to do binary classification on a dataset includes 5996 examples. ~800 of this examples belongs to class 1 and the rest is class 0. Since there is a huge gap between the examples, I have used SMOTE with tomek and een which applies over sampling and under sampling. The problem is when I train the classifier with the enhanced data after preprocessing,smote and tomek or een, and give the test set which is seperated from the total data after preprocessing, it gives a F1 score above 0.99. However, when I preprocess only a partion, 4996 examples, of the dataset and train the classifier with it then test the classifier with the remaining 1000 examples the F1 score is reduced to ~0.80. I couldnt find the reason for this situation. I would be happy if someone can explain.